# iterar una variable y pasar al siguiente si existe php

Tags: php, html

Estoy construyendo una proyección estimada de una llegada de un producto a mi bodega.

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos donde cada `producto` tiene un código único, una descripción y una cantidad.
Luego tengo otra tabla llamada tránsitos la cual almacena el código único del producto, una cantidad, una fecha, y un puerto destino. **PERO TODO ESTO ESTÁ CONCATENADO EN UN GROUP_CONCAT**

tabla transito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces: el primer código ATA0000060 tiene como cantidad a llegar: 240, fecha estimada de llegada: 2021-12-30 y un puerto de 1, lo que se ve en la imagen 240/2021-12-30@1. Los caracteres de / y @ son separadores específicos para después en php saber por cual separar.

La lógica es: En mi tabla transito almaceno las cantidades unitarias que estarían por llegar en una fecha futura por ejemplo, código ATA0000060: 240 unidades están por llegar el día 2021-12-30 en el puerto #1.

Si se fijan hay varios códigos que tienen múltiples llegadas de mercancías, estas están separadas por una coma (,)
El código AB000005190 tiene 3 registros de tránsitos por llegar, separados por 2 comas, esto nos da a entender que: si en `datos_transito` no existen comas(0) significa que tenemos un registro, si existe una coma estarían llegando 2 registros, si aparecen dos comas tendríamos 3 registros y así sucesivamente...

Una vez aclarado esto, viene lo divertido..
En HTML y php necesito mostrar todos los tránsitos venideros a partir de hoy (27/09/2021) hasta el día (27-09-2022), es decir un año. para esto programé un bucle for así:

```
    for ($u=1; $u <360; $u++) { 
            $fechaAMostrar2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fechaActualMysql."+ $u"." day"));
}
```

Este for me muestra todos los días de hoy hasta el 27/09 del otro año
Donde `$fechaActualMysql` es la fecha actual de hoy, funciona perfecto.

Explicaré a groso modo lo que quiero obtener: Luego de mostrar las fechas como encabezado, **necesito mostrar en pantalla cuando está entrando una cantidad en esa fecha especifica en la pantalla** es decir si `$fechaActualMysql` == La fecha en mi registro, tome la cantidad de ese registro y lo muestre, es sencillo cuando solo tienes un registro por recorrer, pero cuando tienes más de uno se complica..

El siguiente código funciona perfecto cuando hay un registro, cunado hay más de dos no logro mostrar la cantidad bien, ni tampoco validarlo, ya que si un registro tiene mas de una coma dará algún error de variable no conocida.

```
// LA VARIALE $DATOS_TRANSITO ME DEVUELVE TODOS LOS TRANSITOS AGRUPADOS ES DECIR OUTPUT: 50/2021-01-10@1
            // DONDE 50 = TRA_CANTIDAD, 2021-01-10 = TRA_FECHA, 1 = TRA_PUERTO
                $datos_transito = $row['datos_transito'];
           // LA VARIALE $CONTADOR ME DEVUELVE TODOS LOS TRANSITOS INDIVIDUALES SEPARADOS POR LA COMA, ES DECIR SI &CONTADOR_DE_REGISTROS = 0
           // QUIERE DECIR QUE EXISTE UN TRANSITO, SI ES IGUAL A 1 QUIERE DECIR QUE EXISTE 2 TRANSITOS, SI ES IGUAL A 2 QUIERE DECIR QUE EXISTEN 3 TRANSITOS ETC..
                $contador_de_registros = substr_count($datos_transito,',');
            // CONVIERTE DE ARRAY A STRING
                $datos_transito_string = strval($datos_transito);
                
            // SEPARADORES (NO USADOS EN ESTE EJERCICIO)
                $sp_registro = ", ";
                $sp_cantidad = "/";
                $sp_fecha = "@"; 
            // DATOS SEPARADOS
                $registro_a_array = explode(',', $datos_transito_string);
                $primer_registro = $registro_a_array[0];
                $primer_caracter =  $primer_registro[0];
                $segundo_registro = $registro_a_array[1];
                // $tercer_registro = $registro_a_array[2];
                 $todos_registros = $primer_registro . '/' .$segundo_registro;
               
                    for ($u=1; $u <$DiasCal; $u++) {                       
                       $fechaAMostrar2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fechaActualMysql."+ $u"." day"));
                       
                       $busqueda = str_contains($primer_registro,$fechaAMostrar2);

                        if ($busqueda != true) {
                            $transito_cantidad = 0;
                        }else{
                            $tra_cantidad_ex = explode('/', $primer_registro);
                            $tra = $tra_cantidad_ex[0];
                            $transito_cantidad = intval($tra);
                            
                        }

                        <td> <?php echo $transito_cantidad ?></td>
```

Lo ideal sería iterar el primer transito, tomar la cantidad y pasar a el siguiente transito si existe, si no pare.

Adjunto este excel que espero ayude a explicar mejor el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no se entiende alguna parte, favor hacerlo saber!

Comment: Te harías un gran favor si normalizas esa tabla; te va a salir *"mas caro el caldo que las albóndigas"*.

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo @Sal en los comentarios, lo mejor sería normarlizar la tabla `transito`, así las queries serán mucho mas sencillas.

En lo personal trataría de resolver todo lo posible en la base de datos, de tal forma que el código php quede lo mas sencillo posible.

Con está query (para MySql >= 8.0) puedes "normalizar" (no es la normazliación a la que hago referencia al principio, aquí solo obtenemos los datos normalizados, pero en la base de datos siguen estando desnormalizados) la información de la tabla `transito`, de tal forma que te retorne cada estimación de la llegada de un producto en una fila aparte, filtrando por fecha (desde hoy hasta un año).

```
WITH RECURSIVE trans_norm AS (SELECT pro_codigo, 
                                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(datos_transito, ',', 1) AS dt, 
                                  1 AS i
                           FROM transito
                     
                           UNION ALL
                     
                           SELECT t.pro_codigo, 
                                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.datos_transito, ',', tn.i + 1), ',', -1) AS dt, 
                                  tn.i + 1 AS i
                           FROM transito AS t 
                           INNER JOIN trans_norm AS tn ON t.pro_codigo = tn.pro_codigo
                           WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.datos_transito, ',', tn.i + 1), ',', -1) != SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.datos_transito, ',', tn.i), ',', -1)
)

SELECT pro_codigo, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, '/', 1) AS cantidad,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, '@', 1), '/', -1) AS fecha_estimada,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, '@', -1) AS puerto
FROM trans_norm
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, '@', 1), '/', -1) BETWEEN '2021-09-27' AND '2022-09-27';
```

Salida (con datos de ejemplo):

| pro_codigo | cantidad | fecha_estimada | puerto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAT0000060 | 240 | 2021-12-30 | 1 |
| AB0005190 | 100 | 2021-10-04 | 1 |
| AB0005190 | 100 | 2021-11-02 | 1 |
| AB0005190 | 100 | 2022-01-09 | 1 |

Luego lo único que tendrás que hacer en php es transponer el resultado (que las fechas te queden como columnas).

No se si entendí bien la última parte, pero ahora especificando la fecha (creo que en tu caso es la fecha actual) te será mas sencillo saber cual es la cantidad para ese fecha.

**con PHP**

Otra solución podría ser que al recibir los datos desde la base de datos, los organices utilizando una estructura mas conveniente, la cual te facilite la iteración sobre los mismos, por ejemplo (tendrías que buscar la estructura mas útil para ti):

```
<?php

//Los datos de transito como llegan desde la base de datos:
$transito = [['AAT0000060', '240/2021-12-30@1'], ['AB0005190', '100/2021-10-04@1,100/2021-11-02@1,100/2022-01-09@1']];

function normalizarTransitos($transito) {
    $sp_registro = ",";
    $sp_cantidad = "/";
    $sp_fecha = "@";
    $resultado = [];

    foreach($transito as $prodTrans) {
        foreach(explode($sp_registro, $prodTrans[1]) as $trans) {
            list($cantidad, $fechaPuerto) = explode($sp_cantidad, $trans);
            list($fecha, $puerto) = explode($sp_fecha, $fechaPuerto);

            $resultado[] = ['producto' => $prodTrans[0], 'cantidad' => $cantidad, 'fecha' => $fecha, 'puerto' => $puerto];
        }
    }

    return $resultado;
}

$datosOrganizados = normalizarTransitos($transito);

?>
```

$datosOrganizados:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'producto' => 'AAT0000060', 'cantidad' => '240', 'fecha' => '2021-12-30', 'puerto' => '1', ), 1 => array ( 'producto' => 'AB0005190', 'cantidad' => '100', 'fecha' => '2021-10-04', 'puerto' => '1', ), 2 => array ( 'producto' => 'AB0005190', 'cantidad' => '100', 'fecha' => '2021-11-02', 'puerto' => '1', ), 3 => array ( 'producto' => 'AB0005190', 'cantidad' => '100', 'fecha' => '2022-01-09', 'puerto' => '1', ), )
```